# Static and memory management in Monotouch

Tags: xamarin.ios

We know the static vs. singleton debate, so this question isn't about legitimacy of the static keyword.

When you have a static class, how is the memory for that handled by Monotouch. Are its members removed when a memory warning is received? Are there any guidelines regarding use of static classes in Monotouch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Static classes and members will hang around the lifetime of your application.

Generally I wouldn't worry about static classes.  The largest thing to worry about is making sure you are properly cleaning things up in `ViewDidUnload` in all your controllers.

Here you should:

- Dispose and set any outlets to null (`ReleaseDesignerOutlets` will do this in later versions of MonoTouch) you have to do it yourself for any views created from code
- Do the same for any instances of UIImage, UIFont, etc. that are created in `ViewDidLoad`
- `ViewDidUnload` should be a mirror image of `ViewDidLoad`

`ViewDidUnload` is called on low memory conditions for controllers that are not currently on screen, such as ones down the stack in `UINavigationControllers`, etc.

In addition, you might want to hook into the low memory notification from `UINotificationCenter` on any helper classes that cache UIImage, UIFont, etc.

Freeing up views and images will free up much more memory that you would get by how much memory static classes are using.

Comment: Good stuff. Thinking of ditching static in favour of instance object (i.e. creating and destroying resources every time the static class would have been called).

Comment: @jonathanpeppers Just FYI: future versions of iOS might no longer call ViewDidUnload and ViewWillUnload...you might want to checkout latest WWDC videos.

Comment: This would effect MonoTouch in general, `ReleaseDesignerOutlets` is generated by MonoDevelop.  Do you have a link to one of these videos?

Comment: FYI for new people finding this. iOS 6 no longer calls `ViewDidUnload`, Apple is now in favor of entire `UIViewControllers` being disposed and cleaned up.